# chrome.webstore.install() failure detail string error codes?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I can't seem to find the failure detail string error codes for `chrome.webstore.install()` 's failure callback... For that matter, I'm not sure if there's documentation for this part of Chrome app development??

Answer (score 0):

From https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/inline_installation#triggering

> This function [the failure callback] is invoked when inline installation does not successfully complete. Possible reasons for this include the user canceling the dialog, the linked item not being found in the store, or the install being initiated from a non-verified site. The callback is given a failure detail string as a parameter. You may wish to inspect or log that string for debugging purposes, but you should not rely on specific strings being passed back.